# How are cosmology and astronomy fields of science?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy

If a scientific field is defined as one that follows the [scientific method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhLBb.png), then it needs to have reproducible experiments. But this is not possible in cosmology and astronomy, because how can one test star formation in a lab? In these fields, one just simply observes nature and accepts whatever it gives you, and then one formulates conclusions based off of their observations.

So are these non-scientific fields because there is no experimentation?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method): “The process in the scientific method involves making conjectures (hypotheses), deriving predictions from them as logical consequences, and then carrying out experiments **or empirical observations** based on those predictions.’

Comment: Where did your flowchart come from? (Not from a cosmologist or astronomer!)

Comment: Why are you reducing cosmology and astronomy to just be concerned with star formation?

Comment: There is no one scientific method. Science is a loose collection methods and values. For any more precise definition, one can always find counter-examples.

Comment: Who says you can't do experiments in astrophysics? From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process "[Astrophysicist] Hoyle went to Fowler's lab at Caltech and said that there had to be a resonance of 7.68 MeV in the carbon-12 nucleus. [...] Hoyle was back in Cambridge when Fowler's lab discovered a carbon-12 resonance near 7.65 MeV a few months later, validating his prediction".

Comment: Before you downvote this question, please consider that this is a new contributor and that this question might come from genuine confusion and maybe was not meant as provocative as it might sound to some people. 

I think some of the comments and answers already provided are much more helpful in clarifying what appears to be a misunderstanding or at least too narrow definition of the term "scientific method". Consider upvoting those instead of downvoting the question.

Comment: @Zaus Keep in mind that down votes can be made for any reason. There is no way to know what those reasons are unless users comment saying their reason. Maybe someone did down vote just because they were rubbed the wrong way. But maybe others down voted because they think the question is subjective or isn't a good fit for the site. Down votes aren't always "dislike buttons". Additionaly, I don't think one should judge a post based on the user who made it. If one thinks a post deserves a down vote then they should do that no matter the status of the author.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I don't mean to dictate anybody what to do, I only wanted to prompt people to consider that this possibly was meant differently than it might come across. I am a cosmologist and was rubbed the wrong way at first, but then thought to myself that my mum could have asked this question without any ill will, which made me reconsider my reaction.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong, here is why.

Astronomy is an observational science. Its program is to collect data which will be of potential use to astrophysicists and cosmologists, and to determine the presence or absence of specific objects whose existence is predicted in models proposed by astrophysicists and cosmologists. Accomplishing these goals requires the continuous invention of new observational methods and continuous improvement of existing ones, both of which are themselves products of the scientific method and require extensive experimentation.

Astrophysics and cosmology are both grounded in physics and mathematics and these fields have become experimental with the advent of supercomputers, which allow astrophysicists and cosmologists to create and then computationally test models of things like the evolution of galactic structure- and then compare the predictions of those experimental models with observations made by the astronomers.

In addition, high energy particle collider experiments duplicate the conditions present in the very very early universe, and the results of those scientific experiments inform the model-making efforts of the astrophysicists and cosmologists.

Answer (score 2):

That's a high school level chart for lab work, not the scientific method.

> "*In these fields, one just simply observes nature and accepts whatever it gives you, and then one formulates conclusions based off of their observations.*"

No, this is not what you do. The point is to make models that make predictions, then test those predictions *against recorded data* (not experiments). Note that "prediction" doesn't always mean predicting things that have not happened yet. It also means also predicting results, even if those results were recorded at the same time you collected your input data. That's how you check. You run your recorded input data through your model and see whether the model's output matches (predicts) the recorded result.

The crux here is recorded data; not experiments. It doesn't matter how you get it as long as it is real and accurate. Consider that an experiment *is* just observing how nature behaves to get recorded data. Just a more convenient one than observing natural events. But if you can't make an experiment, then you have to search and wait for an appropriate natural event to occur to collect data to test your model against.

This makes sense. After all, do you care how a wing flies in a wind tunnel? Do you care how a star forms in a lab? I sure don't. I care how the wing flies in the sky and how a real star forms in space. The ultimate goal is to apply the model to real things outside of a lab so there's literally zero point if you're only ever going to apply your model in a lab. But experiments in a lab, if you can do them, are super convenient and controlled compared to the real world so they are very helpful to speed things along. The control makes them easier to interpret but you have to be careful because it also makes them unnatural which matters because what we ultimately care about is what happens in the real world, not a lab.

If your model output doesn't match the result, you tweak your model so it does and then you have to test it against data that was not used to make your model, otherwise it would be circular reasoning. This data might be new, but could also be old having been recorded previously; as long as it wasn't used to formulate your model.

Also, let's not forget that making a model that accounts for all observations within its framework, which is full of moving pieces, without needing special cases, is much more difficult than just "making conclusions."

> how can one test star formation in a lab?

You can't, but you can find stars in various stages of development.

Answer (score 1):

Who says there's no experimentation in cosmology & astronomy? Here're some astronomy/cosmology related things you can perform experiments for.

- Take out a telescope and observe if Saturn actually follows Kepler's laws of motion.
- Try to find a black hole in the [mass gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_black_hole#Mass_gaps).
- Try to find blueshifted galaxies very, very far away (if you find this you also verify the [QSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady-state_model#Quasi-steady_state) and there's a good chance you win a Nobel prize).
- Try to find planets orbiting binary stars in the habitable zone.

> how can one test star formation in a lab

By taking out a telescope and observing [star-forming regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_formation#Stellar_nurseries).